# Using CSV for data

Tags: d3.js

I wish to replace this portion of my script (from a dashingd3js tutorials) with a reference to a CSV file with the same data.

```
var lineData = [ { "x": 1,   "y": 5},  { "x": 20,  "y": 20},
                 { "x": 40,  "y": 10}, { "x": 60,  "y": 40},
                 { "x": 80,  "y": 5},  { "x": 100, "y": 60}];
```

The csv is located in the same directory and named 'dataFile.csv'

dataFile.csv:

```
x,y
1,5
20,20
40,10
60,40
80,5
100,60
```

Edit: Trying to incorporate feedback from Lars and d3noob, this is what I tried:

```
//The data for our line
d3.csv("testData.csv", function(error, lineData){
//This is the accessor function we talked about above
 var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
                      .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
                      .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
                      .interpolate("linear");

//The SVG Container
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                                .attr("width", 200)
                                .attr("height", 200);

//The line SVG Path we draw
var lineGraph = svgContainer.append("path")
                        .attr("d", lineFunction(lineData))
                        .attr("stroke", "blue")
                        .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                        .attr("fill", "none");

}
```

Here is another version of the code which I am editing as I do more research. It currently does not work.

```
//The data for our line
d3.csv("testData.csv", function(d){
    return{
    lineData.x: d.x,
    lineData.y: d.y };
}, function(error, rows) {
console.log(rows);  
});



//This is the accessor function we talked about above
 var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
                      .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
                      .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
                      .interpolate("linear");

//The SVG Container
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                                .attr("width", 200)
                                .attr("height", 200);

//The line SVG Path we draw
var lineGraph = svgContainer.append("path")
                        .attr("d", lineFunction(lineData))
                        .attr("stroke", "blue")
                        .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                        .attr("fill", "none");

}
```

Comment: please post the code you've tried so far and what errors you are getting

Comment: I have added an edit which includes the latest attempt to use csv, it does not produce the line, and the stuff I included inside the csv function is just what I normally had before replacing var lineData with the csv function

Answer (score 2):

Your drawing code needs to stay inside csv callback:

```
d3.csv("testData.csv", function(data){
    // this converts data to number
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.x = +d.x;
        d.y = +d.y;
    });

    // rest of drawing code
    ...
});
```

See another example here:

http://vida.io/documents/QZZTrhk7SmfChczYp

It's easier to debug if you can post link to working code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the file through an asynchronous request with [`d3.csv`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV). Example code:

```
d3.csv("dataFile.csv", function(error, data) {
  // do something exciting with data
}
```

Comment: Perhaps also use `lineData` instead of `data` (just in case the rest of your code uses it)